# Amplify build fails with [Error: Command failed with exit code 1: pipenv --venv]

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-amplify

I am building a website with AWS Amplify. This website uses amongst other things, several Python Lambda functions.

Today, when building I get the following error message :

```
 Received error [Error: Command failed with exit code 1: pipenv --venv
No virtualenv has been created for this project(PATH_TO_ONE_OF_THE_FUNCTIONS) yet!
Aborted!] running command [pipenv --venv]
```

(I have replaced the path with PATH_TO_ONE_OF_THE_FUNCTIONS because every time I try to redeploy the build it gives this error with a different function)

I have not changed anything in the backend since my last build (which was successful), I have only been working on the frontend.

I have no idea what is causing pipenv --venv to fail.

Here is my amplify.yml file :

```yaml
version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm ci --force
    build:
      commands:
        - npm run build
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: build
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
backend:
  phases:
    build:
      commands:
        - update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/local/bin/python3.9
        - /usr/local/bin/python3.9 -m pip install --upgrade pip
        - /usr/local/bin/pip3.9 install --user pipenv==2022.4.8
        - amplifyPush --simple
```

I am using the latest version of the Amplify CLI (12.1.0) on Mac. When running amplify push on my command prompt it doesn't raise any errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you change your backend command like this and try again?

```
backend:
  phases:
    build:
      commands:
        - update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/local/bin/python3.9 11
        - /usr/local/bin/pip3.9 install --user pipenv==2022.4.8
        - amplifyPush --simple
```

Comment: your solution seems to be working. An alternative solution I found is removing the amplifyPush command, as I already push everything manually before building the app. Thx !

Comment: This saves my day. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. For me the solution didn't worked and I resolved it by a solution I don't think is optimal. In my amplify.yml I manually go create the pipenv for the functions adding that line for each function before the amplifyPush --simple.

```
- export CUR_PWD=$(pwd)
- cd $CUR_PWD/amplify/backend/function/<FunctionFolder> && pipenv install --python /usr/local/bin/python3.9 && cd $CUR_PWD
```